# Sass loop for generating dynamic ratio-semantic classes

Tags: css, loops, grid, sass

I'm trying to write a Sass loop that will create grid setup with ratio semantics.

**I started off with:**

```
$columns:       12 !default;  

@mixin widths-setup($namespace: "") {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns { 
        .width-#{$i} { 
            width: percentage($i/$columns); 
        } 
    }
}
```

**which produces:**

```
.width-1 {  width: 8.33333%; }

.width-2 {  width: 16.66667%; }

...

.width-12 {  width: 100%; }
```

**What I would like to produce**, presumably using @if condition is

```
.width-1-1 {  width: 100%; }

.width-1-2 {  width: 50%; }

.width-2-2 {  width: 100%; }

.width-1-3 {  width: 33.3333%; }

.width-2-3 {  width: 66.66667%; }

.width-3-3 {  width: 100%; }

...

.width-1-12 {  width: 8.3333%; }

.width-2-12 {  width: 16.6666%; }

.width-3-12 {  width: 25%; }

...

.width-12-12 {  width: 100%; }
```

Each class starts with width, second number increases by one during each step in the loop until it equals {$i}, and the third number is the increase of {$i} which will stop at the number assigned to $columns variable.

Although there will be unnecessary classes (width-1-1, width-2-2, width-3-3, etc.) which will all equal the same width but that bloat doesn't concern me at this time.

Comment: Why would you use Sass to *purposely* generate unsemantic class names?

Comment: First off - your comment was not very helpful. Secondly, my intent is to utilize extend for semantic markup, but that's besides the point. Lastly, ratio's are semantic if you consider certain content scenarios which you are unaware of. Thank you Cimmanon for your wonderful observation.

Comment: Ratios have nothing to do with semantics 99% of the time, they are entirely a visual property.  If you had mentioned that you were doing this for `@extend` purposes, I would have told you that it is a completely inefficient of approaching the problem because of code bloat (see:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/27910/26722) and because of the inability to use `@extend` across media queries.  Anything else you'd like to share?

Comment: At what point did I say anything about the need for a media query? I even said that code bloat is not a concern of mine. So basically what you are saying is you are a critic with no answers... be gone troll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$columns: 12 !default;  

@mixin widths-setup($namespace: "") {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns { 
        $cols: $i;
        @for $k from 1 through $cols { 
            .width-#{$k}-#{$i} {
                width: percentage($k/$cols); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should output your expected (but still bloated) result.

Comment: Thanks, Lar_zzz. I can now use placeholder selectors to control the bloat with another mixin to enable symantic & single class names in the HTMl as well as maintain lean css.